# FormClosing with CloseReason = UserClosing doesn't work expectedly?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a main form, in the class of this form, I declare another form. This form lives with the main form until the main form is unloaded. There is a button on the main form, clicking this button will show the member form (I mentioned above). I want to prevent the member form from closing when user closes that form and I added the following FormClosing event handler for that form:

```
private void MemberForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
   if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing){
       e.Cancel = true;
       Hide();
   }
}
```

That works OK for that form. However if user closes the main form, this form is not closed, and it's hidden somewhere making my application seem to run silently. I want this form also to be closed. This is very simple by adding some FormClosed event handler for my main form to close the member form manually. Closing it manually is OK, but why do I have to do that? It seems that when user closes the main form, the FormClosing event of the member form is fired with a parameter FormClosingEventArgs passed in and the CloseReason is the same as the CloseReason of the main form (which is UserClosing). I don't understand this, I thought the CloseReason of the form is UserClosing only when user clicks on the X button, I thought the CloseReason for my member form is something like "MainFormClosing".

Is there some way to close the member form automatically as by default?

## UPDATE

Here is the method showing the member form (showing it as a dialog):

```
private void ShowMemberForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     memberForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

But I don't think this matters, because when I load my main form, even I don't need to click on the ShowMemberForm button, and try closing my main form first, it doesn't still close the member form.
Thanks!

## UPDATE

There is something strange here, I've tried commenting out the line `e.Cancel = true`, or even all the FormClosing event handler and the problem is still there. This is so strange, it works OK before, I've just added the member form and this form relates to some Thread handling, but the thread starts only when a button on the member form is clicked. I didn't click that button.

Comment: Could you show the function that opens the secondary form? Do you pass the owner form in the Show/ShowDialog method?

Comment: Do you mean that your application is still running in the background, when the main form is closed?

Comment: I will try to pass the owner form as in `memberForm.ShowDialog(this);` and check if in the FormClosing event the CloseReason is now `FormOwnerClosing`

Comment: Yes, I understand that it still runs because the member form is not closed because the code in the FormClosing event handler canceled it (and just hid it).

Comment: How can a user close your MainForm, when MemberForm is shown by ShowDialog()?

Comment: @JohnWillemse probably, first the modal dialog is closed with close button or something (but in reality it is hidden) then the MainForm is closed, but the hidden form still runs and prevents the application to close

Comment: Environment.Exit(0); Problem solved:)

Comment: @Mobstaa, the problem is I want to understand what the problem is, closing any process is very easy and there are many ways to do.

Comment: I just updated my question, the problem seems to be different from what I thought...

Comment: Is your main form an MDI Form?

Comment: @Needo no, my main form is a normal form, as I said in my update, this problem has just occurred, I suspect it might be a running background thread but I even didn't start that thread (the only way is clicking on a button).

Comment: In that case, the second option from proposed workaround should work for you.

Comment: Of course, the workaround should work, but even Application.Exit() or Environment.Exit() doesn't change anything, I had to use Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(). However I want to understand what the matter is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is set a flag when programatically closing

so in the MemberForm

```
private bool _ForceClose = false; 
public void ForceClose()
{
    _ForceClose = true; 
    this.Close(); 
}

private void MemberForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
   if(!_ForceClose)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
       Hide();
   }
}
```

Then in your MainForm you can call

```
memberForm.ForceClose();
```

From within your MainForms FormClosing method or from your MainForms Dispose() or Deconstructor.
It's low tech, but it works. Im not sure if you should put _ForceClose = true in your MemberForm's Dispose method, i'm fairly certain when it gets there its already been closed BUT it couldn't really hurt.